# libuv event loop and libcurl

Tags: c, networking, libuv

i see below sample code from [An example on how to use libuv with libcurl](https://gist.github.com/clemensg/5248927#file-curl_libuv_example-c)

the main function looks like below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    if (argc <= 1)
        return 0;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init cURL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uv_timer_init(loop, &timeout);

    curl_handle = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_setopt(curl_handle, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, handle_socket);
    curl_multi_setopt(curl_handle, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, start_timeout);

    while (argc-- > 1) {
        add_download(argv[argc], argc);
    }

    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    curl_multi_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

im confused on how to event loop get going. because it looks like when we execute this line

```
uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
```

there is no pending event in the loop at all so in theory shouldnot the loop exit immediately?

the callback handle_socket should have no changes to run. there is no chance for the `curl_perform()` to run which is set up in the callbacks of curl socket callbacks.

anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: There is a pending event, there's a timer added in uv_timer_init(loop, &timeout);, as well as stuff added in handle_socket()

Answer (score 1):

`uv_timer_init(loop, &timeout)` is not pending socket so it does not block uv loop because it does not active (you can check uv_handle_active)
But `curl_multi_add_handle` calls timeout callback function (`start_timeout`) and this function start `timeout` timer and uv_run calls `on_timeout` callback.
You can test it just move `curl_multi_setopt(curl_handle, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, start_timeout);` after `add_download` loop and it stops to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `uv_run`:

```
/*
* This function runs the event loop. It will act differently depending on the
* specified mode:
* - UV_RUN_DEFAULT: Runs the event loop until the reference count drops to
* zero. Always returns zero.
* - UV_RUN_ONCE: Poll for new events once. Note that this function blocks if
* there are no pending events. Returns zero when done (no active handles
* or requests left), or non-zero if more events are expected (meaning you
* should run the event loop again sometime in the future).
* - UV_RUN_NOWAIT: Poll for new events once but don't block if there are no
* pending events. Returns zero when done (no active handles
* or requests left), or non-zero if more events are expected (meaning you
* should run the event loop again sometime in the future).
*/
```

In your case, you're calling `uv_run` with `UV_RUN_DEFAULT`, and your reference count never goes to zero. This means that the loop will actually block until you destroy all its handles and references. If you, however, had run the loop with `UV_RUN_NOWAIT`, the function *would* return immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Register an async watcher. Use `uv_async_init` to force Looping forever. Then post and deal all new request in async callback.